# Reorder array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of arrays

```
  array (size=2)
  'login' => 
    array (size=3)
      20 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(File)[3]
      10 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(Database)[4]
      5 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(Closure)[5]
```

I'm trying to reorder the position of the keys in the second level arrays (where it says 20, 10, 5) so the result should be

```
array (size=2)
      'login' => 
        array (size=3)
          5 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                object(File)[3]
          10 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                object(Database)[4]
          20 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                object(Closure)[5]
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do that so please help

Comment: Specifically, `ksort($yourArray['login']);`

Comment: use array_reverse($array);  or ksort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
ksort($array['login']);
```

This will sort the array keys so they are ascending.  If you wanted them descending you would do

```
krsort($array['login']);
```

PHP has lots of handy functions for sorting arrays

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Array Sorting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and find out, that 'ksort' is your choice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try PHPs ksort function on your second level array: http://php.net/ksort

It will sort your array by key while maintaining the key-data-associations

Answer (score 0):

PHP has [a variety of array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

In your case, the most appropriate would seem to be [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), which is summarised thus:

> Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations.

As pointed out in the comments, your particular example is already in the reverse of the required order; if this can be guaranteed, you could also use [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), being sure to pass the optional `$preserve_keys` parameter as `true`.

Specifically, you want to re-order the sub-array with the key `'login'`; assuming your overall array is called `$data`, you would  want to write this:

```
ksort($data['login']);
// note no need for an assignment, as PHP's sort functions act in-place
```

or this:

```
$data['login'] = array_reverse($data['login'], true);
// assign back to the original variable, as array_reverse() returns a new array
```